Transparent and taskbar hidden game in unity
im trying to make an overlay, but ive come across a problem in which setting the window transparency cancels out the taskbar visibility and vice versa.
Full code:
Start()
        // get the current window
        hWnd = GetActiveWindow();
        MARGINS margins = new MARGINS { cxLeftWidth = -1 };
        DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, ref margins);

        //make the window transparent
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT); // set the window to be transparent

        SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); // set the window to be topmost

        // hide icon from taskbar
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE2) | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);

Update()
        //raycast from mouse pointer to detect colliders and toggle the windows being click-thru
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        Vector3 worldPosition = displayCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

        Vector2 mousePosition0 = displayCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePosition0, Vector2.zero, Mathf.Infinity, ~overlayLayers);

        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            SetClickThrough(false);
        }
        else
        {
            SetClickThrough(true);
        }

SetClickThough(bool)
private void SetClickThrough(bool clickthrough)
    {
        if (clickthrough)
        {
            SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
        }
        else
        {
            SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_LAYERED);
        }
    }

So the problem is that the Update function SetClickThrough is resetting my window being visible on the taskbar.
Win32:
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    private const int GWL_EXSTYLE2 = -0x14;
    private const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x0080;

    const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;

    const uint WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x00080000;
    const uint WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;

    static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);

